# node_modules dir being included in module published to NPM registry

Tags: node.js, npm

I published my module to the NPM registry. When I installed it using

```
npm install --save-dev X
```

I see that the node_modules folder was included in the install, such that when I go to project Y which depends on X, I see:

```
Y/node_modules/X/node_modules
```

How is this possible?

My .npmignore file in my X project is as follows:

```
.idea
node_modules
bower_components
internal-docs
```

Anyone know what could be up?

Comment: Your package X has it's own dependency with version different from what you have in the root node_modules. The effect you observe is not because NPM published your node_modules folder.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. When I test locally my lib is working as expected, but when I publish it generated Y/node_modules/X/node_modules and that causes problems to the lib and it ends up not working as expected/breaking. I can't understand where Y/node_modules/X/NODE_MODULES is coming from and being generated after npm publish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to add `node_modules` to your `.npmignore`; it is [ignored by default](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package):

> Additionally, everything in `node_modules` is ignored, except for bundled dependencies. npm automatically handles this for you, so don't bother adding `node_modules` to `.npmignore`.

The `npm install` command will naturally install the package's dependencies that are listed in its `package.json` file. It is a normal part of the `npm install` process to install the whole dependencies tree, otherwise the package wouldn't really work.

If you want to be really sure, you can use the [`npm pack`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack) command to generate a tarball (similar to a zip file) that you can inspect and see what files are actually published when you run `npm publish`.